# What do I do with the iso of 14.04 and 13.10 to use Ubuntu on my windows 7 computer?

Tags: 13.10

What do  I do with the iso?  I did install with Wubi last year but now I have a new computer.

Comment: If new system you also need to know about UEFI in addition to standard install screens:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system AND: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score -1):

Per the official Ubuntu documentation [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick), download the application available [here](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download), run the application, and point it towards your .iso file (you will need a USB drive of at least 2 gigs). Wait for the application to finish doing its thing then get ready:

With the USB stick still in your computer, restart your computer. With any hope your machine will sound like its starting normally, but in stead of seeing the windows loading screen, you will see a purple background with Ubuntu in white lettering. If you've gotten this far, you'll be taken into what's called a "Live Session" of Ubuntu. Basically, the operating system is running off your USB drive, you can do anything you feel like doing (I recommend playing around and trying to figure out how to do things, it will be different from Windows). If you decide you like it, double click the icon on the desktop that says "Install Ubuntu" at this point you'll be given the option to either erase Windows, or partition to install along side it. I'm going to assume you want to install along side your Windows partition, so choose that and the rest should be fairly straight forward.

It sounds like you've used Ubuntu before, but are more comfortable with Windows, so I'm going to refer you to the Linux Mint page (linuxmint.com). Mint is built on top of Ubuntu, and is designed to be easier for people coming from Windows to get used to, but of course feel free to choose any Linux distro you like.

Finally, if when you restart your computer you in stead see Windows loading, wait for it to load, then restart your computer again. You will need to access the computer's BIOS by pressing a certain key (usually escape or delete). At this point I can't help you much more without knowing exactly what computer you're using, but hunt around for something that looks like "boot order" and be sure "USB" or "removable" is at the top of the list, but also being sure not to completely remove any from the list, just reorder them.

Best of luck, and please add [SOLVED] to the title of this thread if this helped you out, otherwise, feel free to come back for help!